# Carp: Bizarre copy of ARRAY in sassign. Any fixes?

Tags: perl, die, carp

I'm suffering an annoying problem when trying to `die` from within an `eval`.

The code is as follows;

```
$status = eval { $self->$func( @{$y->{args}} ); };
```

in this case `$self->$func` points to a handler that detaches to a certain page on error like this:

```
sub detach
{
    my $self   = shift;
    my $url    = shift;
    my @params = @_;

    if( $url !~ /^\// )
    {
        $url = '/' . $self->namespace . '/' . $url;
    }
    $url =~ s/\sat.*$//;
    print STDERR $self->uri . ": Detaching to " . $url . "\n";

    die "REDIR:$url";
}
```

this *should* place `"REDIR:$url"` into `$@` so it's available when the `eval` exits.

However, instead Carp.pm dies, I assume somewhere in the internals of `die` with

> ```
> Bizarre copy of ARRAY in sassign at /usr/share/perl/5.10/Carp.pm line 182
> ```

Looking around there is some suggestion that there is a bug deep in perl relating to the stack during die (e.g. http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl5-porters/149248/), however I'm afraid that at this point I'm at the limit of my knowledge of perl and I'm not sure if this is relevant, or what to do about it if it is. `:(`

Does anyone know if there is a way around this problem or another way to pass an error string back from the `eval`, or if I'm reading this incorrectly?

Comment: can you provide a working example?

Comment: I've tried putting the code into an example however it works fine, which leads me to think it's something to do with the article I referenced. At the time I thought I might have an old version of Carp , however that's up to date.  I'll keep trying to get a failing example and post it if I have success.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with the [current stable version](http://www.perl.org/get.html); if you succeed, [file a bug](http://p3rl.org/bug). Your 5.10 is old and [unsupported](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpolicy.html#MAINTENANCE-AND-SUPPORT), chances are good this bug has already been fixed meanwhile.

Comment: Sorry all - I went on holiday.  I'll try the latest version and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the version of Perl I was using.
Upgrading to 5.16.1 resolved the problem.

Comment: Not really, upgrading just does not trigger the Carp bug anymore. Upgrading to 5.16.1 or newer will not necessarily fix the problem (cf. the other answer by leon at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11603591/1905491).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like [#52610](https://rt.perl.org/rt3//Ticket/Display.html?id=52610). Are you using any module that hooks into the debugger that could be the culprit?

Comment: No, I'll try updating to the latest perl and report back.

Comment: Carp hooks into the DB package. Workaround patch [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=969714) (Also is somewhere buried in the link you gave).